# A more compact __repr__ for my numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

When I show an array, the default `__repr__()` method for `ndarray` objects is too big for what I would like to do:

```
a = np.eye(32)
b = {'hello':42, 'array':a}
b
```

produces:

```
{'array': array([[ 1.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
   ..., 
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  1.]]), 'hello': 42}
```

I tried an ugly solution, reassigning `__repr__`:

```
def wow():
    return "wow!"

a.__repr__ = wow
```

which yields an attribution error and I am not surprised:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#11>", line 1, in <module>
    a.__repr__ = wow
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object attribute '__repr__' is read-only
```

I can make a class with a custom **repr** that is what I would like:

```
class NP(object):
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
    def __repr__(self):
        s0, s1 = self.a.shape
        dtp    = self.a.dtype
        return '{}x{} {}'.format(s0, s1, dtp)

A = NP(a)
A
```

now yields:

```
32x32 float64
```

but the tiny problem is that I would now have to access the attribute everywhere. A.sum() fails, A.a.sum() works.

Is there a way to do this using NumPy directly?

Comment: Looks like you want a subclass of `ndarray`, not composition.

Comment: @timgeb that sounds indeed like what I would like to do. See [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53313496/a-more-compact-repr-for-my-numpy-array#comment93507714_53313665)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `np.set_string_function`:

```
>>> def __repr__(self):
...     s0, s1 = self.shape                                                               
...     dtp    = self.dtype                                                                   
...     return '{}x{} {}'.format(s0, s1, dtp)                                                                   
...                                                                                                                 
>>> np.set_string_function(__repr__)                               
>>> np.identity(5)                                                 
5x5 float64
```

For more advanced display, you may want to have a look at `reprlib`.

If on the other hand all you want is to make it a bit shorter `np.set_printoptions` may be your easiest option.

If you need this to apply only to a subset of arrays, then subclassing may indeed be your best option. I'm not sure, though, what the current status of subclassing is with numpy. It used to be fraught with subtleties to say the least.

```
>>> class myarray(np.ndarray):                                                                            
...    def __repr__(self):                                                                                
...        return "wow!"
...                                                                                                                 
>>> np.identity(5).view(myarray)                                                                                  
wow!
```

Comment: I see, that would apply to all arrays, and that is definitely an improvement for me. But I need this to apply to one array, which is why I tried `a.__repr__ = wow`. Can this be pointed to one array instead of all of them?

Comment: @uhoh Not directly, no. But subclassing may work, see updated answer.

Comment: I see what you mean... [Subclassing ndarray is complicated by the fact that new instances of ndarray classes can come about in three different ways. These are...](http://library.isr.ist.utl.pt/docs/numpy/user/basics.subclassing.html) so in this case `set_string_function` might be my best bet. Thanks!

Comment: This worked for me! FWIW, I was trying to get the matrix representation more easily than doing `print(arr)`, which can be done with `np.set_string_function(np.array2string)`.