# I want to the output array to be in same line

Tags: python, numpy

[image]

When I print an array, only four elements in one row are on the same line. I want all the elements in a row to be printed on the same line. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer here covers your question: [A more compact __repr__ for my numpy array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53313496/a-more-compact-repr-for-my-numpy-array)

You could do something like:

```py
import numpy as np
from numpy.core.arrayprint import array_repr

a = np.array([[0.0 for x in range(9)] for y in range(3) ])
a[0,0] = 2.946e6
a[1,1] = 1.363e3
a[2,2] = 2.357e8
b = [a]

print(b)
#[array([[2.946e+06, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00,
#        0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00],
#       [0.000e+00, 1.363e+03, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00,
#        0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00],
#       [0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 2.357e+08, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00,
#        0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00]])]

def __my_repr__(self):
    return array_repr(self).replace('\n', '').replace(' ', '').replace(',', ', ')
np.set_string_function(__my_repr__)
print(b)
#[array([[2.946e+06, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00], [0.000e+00, 1.363e+03, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00], [0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 2.357e+08, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00, 0.000e+00]])]
```